# Vert.x queryStream seems to hang at about 4950 rows

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, vert.x

I am troubleshooting a strange issue with Vertx 3. I've created a request handler for an HTTP route, which queries a PostgreSQL database. It's all very standard and it works, until the row count increases beyond 4950. This is despite using queryStream, which is supposed to scale.

I've simplified the code below to illustrate the problem:

```
dbClient.getConnection(res -> {
                if (res.failed()) {
                    event.fail(500);
                    return;
                }

                try (final SQLConnection conn = res.result()) {
                    conn.queryStream("select x, y, z from large_table", stream -> {
                        if (stream.succeeded()) {
                            final SQLRowStream rowStream = stream.result();

                            rowStream.handler(row -> {
                               // Do something with row here, but leaving it empty now
                            }).endHandler(endHandler -> {
                                response.end();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

How do I go about troubleshooting this?  When I run the query in psql or using regular JDBC in Java SE it has no issues.

If I append "LIMIT 4000" to the query, it works fine.

Or have I misunderstood Vertx's JDBC support, in that I have to execute this as blocking code because it is taking so long?

Comment: This code looks good. Missing some context to understand the problem. Feel free to post on the forum with a reproducer.

Comment: By forum I assume you mean https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vertx  - I will do so, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like upgrading to vert.x 3.5.2 solved the issue. I am not sure what the actual root cause was.